# Count down to a week later from current date and time in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, tkinter

I want to make an app that when run, it will get the current date and time from the user's computer, and then count down to a week later at the time of running.

So for example:

The user runs the app on 06-06-2017 11:00:00, it must do a count down to a deadline a week later and display the deadline date and time, and show a count down of how many days, hours, minutes and seconds are left.

**EDIT:**

So far I have only been able to get the date and time and the time increments normally per second. I am having difficulty decrementing it. Without the last line of the code the time decrements but does not update automatically. I have yet to find a way to perform a count down from a week in advance.

```
def updateTime():
    X = 1
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    s = t.replace(microsecond=0)
    result = s - datetime.timedelta(seconds=X)
    future = s + datetime.timedelta(days=7, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0)
    lblTime.configure(text=result, font=("", 14))
    lblTime.after(100, updateTime)
```

Comment: Right now, this question is just "give me teh codezz". Please show your code, your efforts and where do you get stuck. Also, read [Ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: I know, I'm not proud of it. But I have been playing around with some code and so far I can only get the date and time to increment normally. I have added the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to calculate the target time only *once* instead of getting it every time the `updateTime` handler runs. Furthermore, you can simply do arithmetic on datetime objects to get a timedelta object back which you can then display in your GUI.

Here is an example that is printing the output to the console. You can probably adjust this as needed to make it display in your GUI.

```
import datetime

target_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
target_time = target_time.replace(microsecond=0)

def get_remaining_time():
    delta = target_time - datetime.datetime.now()

    hours = delta.seconds // 3600
    minutes = (delta.seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = delta.seconds % 60
    print('{} days, {} hours, {} minutes, {} seconds'.format(delta.days, hours, minutes, seconds))


while True:
    get_remaining_time()
```